# Where does yum install python on CentOS 6.6?

Tags: python, centos, centos6, yum

I've installed python27 on my CentOS 6.6 system using this command:

```
% yum install python27
```

The install went successfully but I cannot find the python27 executable. It is not in the following places:

```
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
```

Running the `yum` command again tells me that there is nothing to do.

```
[ray@localhost bin]$ sudo yum install python27
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.mit.edu
 * extras: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * rpmforge-extras: apt.sw.be
 * updates: centos-distro.1gservers.com
Setting up Install Process
Package python27-1.1-25.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[ray@localhost bin]$
```

Where could python27 be?

I see no evidence that it is actually installed other than the message saying that it has been installed.  Is there a step I'm missing to get it into /usr/bin?

Comment: Did you try `whereis python` ?

Comment: That's a good command!  But it says this:

python: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

No mention of 2.7

Comment: It should be there: just list all python: ls -ltr /usr/local/bin/pyth*

Comment: Except if python27 is installed in /opt for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
rpm -ql <package name>
```

will show you all files in your installed rpm.

Comment: So you could use
`rpm -ql python27`
and see where your python27 installed.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I see. 

    [ray@localhost bin]$ sudo yum install python27
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 <snip>
Package python27-1.1-25.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[ray@localhost bin]$ rpm -ql python27
(contains no files)
[ray@localhost bin]$ **rpm -ql python**
/usr/bin/pydoc
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2.6
/usr/share/doc/python-2.6.6
/usr/share/doc/python-2.6.6/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/python-2.6.6/README
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

Comment: It's almost good... But you should run `rpm -ql python27` (not `rpm -ql python` - because it's for python 2.6) it will show you the path where python27 is installed.

Comment: Sadly I ran it:  
rpm -ql python27 -->
 (contains no files)

Comment: It seems that 'yum install' is not really doing an install.  There is no python in /usr/local/bin after the install.

Comment: No, I should not say "is not really doing an install", but rather that package python27 could be empty, transitional or something like that.
In this case... 
a) at first `yum info python27` give you some info and may be explanations about this package;

Comment: b) you could try to download rpm-package of python27
`yum install yum-downloadonly`
then `yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=./ python27`

That will download python27.rpm into your current directory.
Then `rpm2cpio python27.rpm |cpio -ivd` could extract the content of  
python27.rpm so you could be sure that there is nothing in this package.

Be careful, probably python27.rpm have some more complicated name (like python27.el6.rpm etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
alternatives --list | grep python
```

This lists all packages along with paths, which have multiple installed versions on the system and then greps python in the list.

Comment: Is there a way to force a reinstall?

Comment: @RaySalemi if you used "yum install python27" as you said, then remove it using "yum remove python27" and then re-run "yum install python27" :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Finally I installed python 2.7 following the instructions in this [document](https://17277917375006573357.googlegroups.com/attach/d93788b1658a124f/Installing%20GCP%20SDK%20python.pdf?part=0.1&vt=ANaJVrEgcsXXEvwj0ZDWCWOJhwgxivrpztPdOhLvhxfdvzIMYex-rOIpELGR7NfoiYkXbltxAE9SU3smPiJgtCjSeh16PeenPnEt-R_Jcln6GIs5UMzbAP0). It compiles python 2.7 using make altinstall, thus you keep the old version:

```
cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-2.7.6.tgz
cd Python-2.7.6
sudo ./configure
sudo make altinstall
```

Check with:

```
python2.7 -V
```

Hope it helps.